# How to change claim values in refresh tokens and bearer authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, bearer-token, refresh-token

I want to change the value of a claim via refresh tokens. My refresh token provider is like this:

```
public class MyRefreshTokenProvider : AuthenticationTokenProvider
{
  public override void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
  {
     ...
     var claim = context.Ticket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.UserData);
     if (claim != null)
     {
         context.Ticket.Identity.RemoveClaim(claim);
         context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, "New Value"));
     }

     context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());
  }

  public override void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
  {
     context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);
  }
}
```

And in the startup class:

```
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
  {
     ...
     RefreshTokenProvider = new MyRefreshTokenProvider()
  });
```

The refresh token request completes with no error. But when I use the new access token, the claim value is still the old one.

Is my approach right? Or how can I change a claim value in the Bearer authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution. I have to extend the `AccessTokenProvider` `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` instead of the `RefreshTokenProvider`:

```
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
   ...
   AccessTokenProvider = new MyAccessTokenProvider(),
   RefreshTokenProvider = new MyRefreshTokenProvider()
});

public class MyAccessTokenProvider : AuthenticationTokenProvider
{
  public override void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
  {
     ...
     var claim = context.Ticket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.UserData);
     if (claim != null)
     {
         context.Ticket.Identity.RemoveClaim(claim);
         context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, "New Value"));
     }

     context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());
  }

  public override void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
  {
     context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);
  }
}

public class MyRefreshTokenProvider : AuthenticationTokenProvider
{
  public override void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
  {
     context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());
  }

  public override void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
  {
     context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);
  }
}
```

According to the `OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler` class in the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth` the `AccessTokenProvider` only can update the refreshing token. For changing the claims the `AccessTokenProvider` should be extended:

```
    private async Task InvokeTokenEndpointAsync()
    {
        ...
        var accessTokenContext = new AuthenticationTokenCreateContext(
            Context,
            Options.AccessTokenFormat,
            ticket);

        await Options.AccessTokenProvider.CreateAsync(accessTokenContext);

        string accessToken = accessTokenContext.Token;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
        {
            accessToken = accessTokenContext.SerializeTicket();
        }
        DateTimeOffset? accessTokenExpiresUtc = ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc;

        var refreshTokenCreateContext = new AuthenticationTokenCreateContext(
            Context,
            Options.RefreshTokenFormat,
            accessTokenContext.Ticket);
        await Options.RefreshTokenProvider.CreateAsync(refreshTokenCreateContext);
        string refreshToken = refreshTokenCreateContext.Token;

        var memory = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] body;
        using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(memory)))
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName(Constants.Parameters.AccessToken);
            writer.WriteValue(accessToken);
            writer.WritePropertyName(Constants.Parameters.TokenType);
            writer.WriteValue(Constants.TokenTypes.Bearer);
            if (accessTokenExpiresUtc.HasValue)
            {
                TimeSpan? expiresTimeSpan = accessTokenExpiresUtc - currentUtc;
                var expiresIn = (long)expiresTimeSpan.Value.TotalSeconds;
                if (expiresIn > 0)
                {
                    writer.WritePropertyName(Constants.Parameters.ExpiresIn);
                    writer.WriteValue(expiresIn);
                }
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(refreshToken))
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName(Constants.Parameters.RefreshToken);
                writer.WriteValue(refreshToken);
            }
         ...
```